# Этимология

Tags: этимология

Какое из слов является исконно русским: *фуражка, кепка, шляпа, картуз*?

Answer (score 1):

Хороший вопрос! Исконно русскими являются слова фуражка и кепка. Хотя кепка - это суффиксальное образование от слова кепи, которое пришло из немецкого языка. А фуражка - суффиксальное образование от французского фураж - корм для животных и буквально обозначает головной убор. который надевают при сборе фуража. **НО:** слова. образованные по русским словообразовательным моделям с помощью русских суффиксов считаются исконно русскими словами. Сравните: Компьютер - заимствованное, компьютерный - русское. Вот такой парадокс.

Comment: >>> слова, образованные по русским словообразовательным моделям с помощью русских суффиксов считаются исконно русскими словами.  

Кем считаются?

Comment: Есть такая точка зрения в языкознании. Мне она тоже не очень нравится. Но приходится считаться. Ссылку на статьи сейчас не дам, если нужно  - попробую найти. Но было время, специально искала материал , т.к. встречались  одно время в тестах для абитуриентов подобные задания.

Comment: Ну вот у Розенталя: Следует подчеркнуть, что в составе собственно русской лексики могут быть и слова с иноязычными корнями, прошедшие путь русского словообразования и обросшие русскими суффиксами, приставками: партийность, беспартийный, агрессивность; линейка, рюмка, чайник; слова со сложной основой: радиоузел, паровоз, а также множество сложносокращенных слов, пополнивших наш язык в XX в.: МХАТ, леспромхоз, стенгазета и др.

Comment: Как Вам: агрессивность - русское слово. Именно потому, что образовано по моделям русского словообразования с помощью русского суффикса.